# javascript get 2 days before and after a specific date

Tags: javascript

I am writing a tampermonkey script and the logic is as follows.

1. make a GET request to fetch a certain value, and this will give me a date in the format '2021-05-01' This is date 1st May 2021.
2. Now I get to the following dates within my javascript. 2 days before and after this date.
3. so I want to calculate the following dates 29th April 2021, 30th April 2021, 2nd May 2021, 3rd May 2021. i.e. '2021-04-29','2021-04-30','2021-05-02','2021-05-03'

Please can someone help me write this.

My current code is as follows

```
//GET request to get a date value and save it to a variable called checkdate
var checkdate = GET-request. 

// add code to get 2 days plus and minus this date. 
var d = new Date(checkdate)
var x = 2
var newd = d.setDate(d.getDate() - x);
var dt = getFullYear() + "-" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt.getDate();
```

So when I run it for the date '2021-05-01', I end up with the following value for newd
1619654400000
and value for dt as
2021-04-29

so now I need to extract the date from this which should be '2021-04-29' and now I have to repeat this same code 4 times. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Start with [*Converting a string to a date in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript/5619588?r=SearchResults&s=3|118.4661#5619588) noting [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results), then see [*Add days to JavaScript Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) (which also covers subtraction). When you've written some code, if you have issues post again.

Comment: @RobG I had added my code but messed up the saving. edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date("2021-05-01").getTime()` return the number of milliseconds and it should look like this `1619827200000` from here you can add or subtract the number of milliseconds for the needed dates like this.

```
let date_milliseconds= new Date(your_date_variable).getTime();
let one_day_millisec=1000*60*60*24;
let one_day_before= new Date(date_milliseconds-one_day_millisec);//If your date is 2021-05-01 this date should be 2021-04-30
```

Same goes for next day

Comment: "2021-05-01" will be parsed as UTC, probably not what the OP expects, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Adding days by adding or subtracting milliseconds is not recommended as days aren't always 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, see [*Add days to JavaScript Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date).